# Change Background Color of the 3D Viewport

Tags: 3d-view

When I work in edit mode and wireframe I have difficulty to visualize the loops of the object. How can I change the background color of the viewport or the color of the wires?
Thanks,
Dov

Comment: You can change all the colors in the user preferences. Go to the file menu, then user preferences. In the "themes" tab, you'll find several presets and a way to customize each part of the UI

Comment: You may want to update the selected answer, pointing to [the one applicable to recent versions.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201475/15265)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the background color by going to: User Preferences > Theme > 3D View > Theme Background Color > **Gradient High/Off**

Note: CTRL + ALT + U opens user preferences immediately.

[image: Where]

[image: What]

You can also change the color of the wire by using Wire and Wire Edit in the same menu.

Comment: In 2.8, its Edit -> Preferences -> Themes -> 3D viewport -> Theme space -> Gradient colors.

Answer (score 7):

In Blender 2.8 go to *Blender Prefs/Themes/3D Viewport*. In the top you find the **Wire Colors**.

If you want to change BG-Color, go to *Blender Prefs/Themes/3D Viewport* and scroll down to **Gradient Colors**.

[image: Wire Color]

[image: Gradient Colors]

Comment: Thanks, this should be the new selected answer. Someone may want to write a plugin for UI customization, allowing the user to select the element to change directly on the interface, instead of trying to force them to find an improbable name in the preferences.

Answer (score 2):

To change the background color in script you can do something like that:

```
bpy.context.user_preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = new_color
```

Comment: for 2.8 it would be.. bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = new_color

Comment: For 2.9: `bpy.context.preferences.themes['Default'].view_3d.` ...

Answer (score 2):

As in **Blender 2.93**, [Atkay's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201475/132229) still applies in order to change 3D viewport's background color from GUI.

To do this programmatically, [sreenivas](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/99342/132229)' comment to this answer works pretty well:

```
bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = new_color
```

To define a new color, you just define its 3 component's values like `(r, g, b)`, with values in the range [0, 1]

**NOTE:** Using `...themes['Default']...`, as commented in a previous answer, makes Blender crash.