# How to change 3D Viewport Color in Blender 2.49b?

Tags: 3d-view, customization

I need to change the 3D viewport background color from the default gray to a higher-contrast color like white, but I can't seem to find an option to do so. This question has been [asked and answered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74445/change-background-color-of-the-3d-viewport) for other versions of Blender, but apparently not for 2.49b (i.e. the steps given don't match my interface, so I assume they're for different versions). **How do I change the 3D viewport color in 2.49b?**

Bonus question: how can I change the grid line color?

Comment: Do you really want answer for 2.49b version? Are there any special reasons for using such old version? Of course interface differs because there was significant change from 2,49 to 2.5x versions, both in interface and API

Comment: I am slowly learning to use the newer versions, but I'm most familiar with 2.49b and still use it for a lot of my projects. But you know what they say... old age is a bitch, and the gray background just isn't working for me anymore.

Comment: You'd do wise to invest your time learning a newer version. I can't even remember if that was configurable back then any more.

Comment: @MikeB I was in your shoes once, I refused to ditch my years of learning the interface and outright waited a year to try 2.5! To ease the migration you can reorder the panels to have the now vertical sidebar at the bottom similar to 2.49.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand the top *Info* window bar, navigate to the *Theme* tab, and press *Add* to create a new one.

From the menus make sure you pick *3D View*, then choose *Background* and adjust the color from the sliders or the color picker as desired.

You can also adjust the grid color by picking *Grid* from the second dropdown.

[image]

Comment: wow! Now we can be archaeology.blender.stackechange!

Comment: Haha indeed! The zip file where this was archived had a considerable layer of dust over the icon. Bet this is the first answer about 2.49 here in a while. :D

Comment: Woot! Thank you Duarte. That GIF was especially helpful and much easier than trying to follow written directions. Kudos!

Comment: We [debated having these on-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167/policy-for-questions-about-older-versions-of-blender) and ultimately decided to leave them be since they are so rare.

Comment: Thats a nice clean GIF, how did you make it? I always get lots of dithering using google image converter

Comment: I always use [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com) thought I can always see some color banding, but I guess that's unavoidable with this file format and the size restrictions here